# update de upload

Tags: php, upload, sql-update

Tô com um problema no caminho para salvar o arquivo de upload. tenho um arquivo php que faz o update que está na pasta processa, e uma pasta upload para guarda os arquivo que foram salvos.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$postador = $_POST['postador'];
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

//Substituindo os caracteres especiais
$original = 
'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜüÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿRr"!@#$%&*
()_-+={[}]/?;:,\\\'<>°ºª';

$substituir = 
'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr                                
';

$arquivo = strtr(utf8_decode($arquivo), utf8_decode($original), 
$substituir);

//Substitui os espaços em branco
$arquivo = str_replace(' ', '-', $arquivo);

//Substitui os Maiúsculos por Minúsculos
$arquivo = strtolower($arquivo);

$caminhofinal = "upload".'/'.$arquivo;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'],$caminhofinal);

$sql_query = "UPDATE posts SET titulo = '$titulo', arquivo = 
'$caminhofinal', descricao = '$descricao', data = NOW(), hora = NOW(), 
postador = '$postador' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query);

if($resultado === TRUE){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-
    label='close'>&times;</a>
                    ID: $id Editado com Sucesso!</div>";

    header("Location: ../professor/lista_conteudo.php");
}  else {
     $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-
     label='close'>&times;</a>
                    Erro ao Editar ID: $id</div>";
     header("Location: ../professor/editar_conteudo.php");
}
```

A questão é que está salvando a url no banco mas não o arquivo na pasta. já tentei colocar na variável $caminhofinal = "../upload".'/'.$arquivo; mas não funcionou. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: Pode ser permissão de pasta, tenta colocar permissão de escrita na sua pasta de caminho final

Answer (score -1):

Como o Gabriel Santos comentou, as opções de pasta são muito importantes neste caso, porém para um bom entendimento do erro é importante também isolar as possibilidades.

Quando eu faço uploads, eu isolo desta forma:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo,$destino)){
    //ok
}else{
    //não ok
}
```

Desse jeito você sabe se o arquivo foi enviado ou não executando a ação dentro da própria checagem if.

Agora para saber qual foi o problema eu sugiro uma abordagem com try catch:

```
try {
    if (!move_uploaded_file( ... )) {
        throw new Exception('Arquivo não Enviado!');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('Motivo: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Abraços!